# MVVM with Data Binding - Navigation in Fragment or ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-databinding, android-navigation

I am confused how to best structure Navigation when using MVVM with Data Binding.

These are my two suggestions, which one is best.

1. Navigation from Fragment using onClickListener

   ```
   private fun setupUIListeners() {
       btnToBrowse.setOnClickListener { it
           navigateToSecondFragment(it)
       }
   }

   private fun navigateToSecondFragment(it: View) {
       val action = FirstFragmentDirections.actionToSecondFragment()
       Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action)
   }
   ```
2. Navigation using Data Binding from ViewModel, which I haven't figured out why it doesn't work yet. I do think it has to do something with that (view) is not equivalent to (it: View) in my first method, not sure though,

```
    class FirstViewModel : ViewModel() {
        fun navigateToSecondFragment(view: View) {
            val action = FirstFragmentDirections.actionToSecondFragment()
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action)
        }
    }
```

and in fragment_first.xml

```
<Button
        ...
        android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewmodel.navigateToSecondFragment(view)}"
        ...
```

However, which of these methods is best?

Comment: you can set onClick in xml without DataBinding `android:onClick="navigateToSecondFragment"`, but i think the first option with `setOnClickListener` is still preferred

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do base your answer on when you say that the first option is preferred?

Comment: Obviously you should use it in your `fragment` in `MVVM`  `viewModel` does not know any thing about `view`